# Unique factorization consequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let R be principal ideal domain and $p$ prime element and $b \in R$, $b\neq 0$, $E=R/(pb)$ module over $R$ and let $E_p$ be submodule consisting of elements with exponent $p$ (there exist positive intiger $r$ so that $p^rx=0$). I need to prove  $E_p=bR/(pb)$. One inclusion is trivial, and for other solution say it follows at once from unique factorization in $R$. 
My try:

Let $x \in E_p$ so $x=a+(pb)$ and $p^ra+(pb)=(pb)$ which implies $p^ra=cpb$ for some $c \in R$. How do I use unique factorization here to prove that $a=by$ for some $y \in R$? What I can conclude from unique factorization in general? In some way I think i can "divide by $p$"?

Comment: This is incomprehensible. Who is $b$ in your first paragraph? Why do you write parentheses in $x=a+(pb)$?

Comment: b is from ring R, any not null element. And I write +(pb) because it is element of quotient module.

Comment: OK, the first paragraph is better now. If you want to say $x$ is the image of $a$ in $E=R/pbR$, you could either (1) just say that in words, or (2) write $x=a+pbR$ (in which the $R$ makes clear you are talking about a coset). I can understand the $(..)$ notation now, but it is really only used as a shorthand in the specific case where $R$ is a ring of _polynomials_, where expanding the full name of $R$ in an ideal $cR$ would be lengthy. Since $R$ is more general here and has a short name, I would stick to just $cR$ here.

Comment: Thank you, I just used same notation as for factor groups (Lang in Algebra used something similar so I thought it is coprehensive)

Comment: By the way, is there by any chance a hypothesis that $b$ is not divisible by $p$? It looks like for $R=\Bbb Z$ and $b=p$ what you say is not true. Independently of that "one inclusion is trivial" is lazy on your part; you probably know _which_ direction you mean, and reading would be easier if you just said which one. Also you probably mean principal _ideal_ domain (which is always an integral domain).

Comment: It is pricipal ideal domain (Lang uses principal entire ring so I just translated wrong from Croatian), also, I don't have any condition on b. I was not sure "right inclusion" is good expression so I  just thougth it would be clear from second paragraf which inclusion it is :-P

Comment: you could just say that the inclusion $bR/(bp)\subseteq E_p$ is trivial. Then when you say the "opposite inclusion", I guess there is not much confusion what _that_ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct statement should be that $E_p=b'R/pbR$, where $b'$ is $b/p^v$, where $p^v$ is the maximum power of $p$ appearing in the factorization of $b$.

The inclusion $b'R/pbR\subseteq E_p$ is obvious, because $p^{v+1}b'z=pbz\in pbR$ for any $z\in R$.

The submodule $E_p$ can be described as the set of cosets $x+(pb)$ such that, for some $k>0$, $p^kx\in(pb)$ or, equivalently, the set of cosets $x+(pb)$ such that, for some $k\ge0$, $p^kx\in(b)$.

If $x+(pb)\in E_p$, then $p^kx=by$. Let $r$ be the maximum exponent such that $p^r$ divides $y$. If $r\ge k$, we have
$$
x=b\frac{y}{p^k}
$$
so $x\in bR$. Otherwise, we get
$$
p^{k-r}x=b\frac{y}{p^r}
$$
and so we can assume $p^kx=pby$ where $p$ does not divide $y$ and $k\ge0$.

Now, consider the factorizations of $x$, $b$ and $y$, writing them as
$$
x=x_0p^up_1^{u_1}\dots p_s^{u_s},\quad
b=b_0p^vp_1^{v_1}\dots p_s^{v_s},\quad
y=y_0p_1^{w_1}\dots p_s^{w_s}
$$
where the exponent can be zero, the primes are all distinct and $x_0$, $b_0$, $y_0$ are units.
Thus we have
$$
x_0p^{u+k}p_1^{u_1}\dots p_s^{u_s}=
b_0y_0p^vp_1^{v_1}\dots p_s^{v_s}p_1^{w_1}\dots p_s^{w_s}
$$
This implies
$$
\begin{cases}
u+k=v\\
u_1=v_1+w_1\\
\dots\\
u_s=v_2+w_s
\end{cases}
$$
In particular $v_i\le u_i$ (for $i=1,2,\dots,s$) and so $b'$ divides $x$.

Note that when $b=p^v$ we have $b'=1$ and indeed $E_p=R/pbR$ in this case. On the other hand, if $p$ does not divide $b$, then $b'=b$ and $E_p=bR/pbR$.

Comment: You seem to accommodate the possibility that $p$ divides $b$. But I think taking $b=p$ makes $E=R/p^2R$, $E_p=E$ which differs from $pR/p^2R$, so the statement would not be true. Maybe I am missing something...

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Fixed statement and argument.